# Shortcut to step back in the block hierarchy in Trackmania Nations Forever's map editor?

Tags: trackmania-forever

In Trackmania Nations Forever's map editor, is there any shortcut to step back in the block hierarchy?

I read on http://bandofscousers.proboards.com/thread/1652/tm2-map-editor-guide :

> Besides using the mouse to click on them, you can use the keyboard
>   keys 1-9 to reach them, and the **^ key to make 1 step back in the block
>   hierarchy.** Then use the mouse to move around the map, and use the
>   mousewheel to select the desired height to place the part.
>   Alternatively, use the cursor keys and the Scroll up/down keys

However  <kbd>^</kbd>  does not seem to work in TMF (the guide was written for TM2).

[image]

Comment: I'm still interested in the answer.

Comment: If anyone has any idea.

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with the right mouse button